# Update system tor

Tags: update

I'm currently running system tor, and its version is `0.3.1.1-alpha-dev`. Every once in a while it asks me to change it by either downgrading it (to 0.2.x)? which sounds mildly reasonable, or upgrading it to `0.3.1.2`, which at the moment of this writing, as far as I can see, doesn't exist.
Is there a reason for the latter suggestion?

Comment: [Update is out now](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/tor-0312-alpha-out-notes-about-0311-alpha).

Comment: Indeed, and thanks, but the question stands.

Comment: Knowing where you see the message and the exact wording might help to figure out what's going on.